# how can a voice glimmer

Tags: meaning

> "Your voice glimmers like a flower in the breeze"

What does *glimmers* mean here? I've searched all the dictionaries and couldn't find an acceptable meaning.

*Glimmers* means "shining" according to the dictionary, so tell me how can the voice shine?

Comment: Maybe don't say "all the dictionaries". Anyway, see [*glimmer*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/glimmer): "4. a faint indication". Other listed definitions and examples may help.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a literary device called [*imagery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imagery).  From the Wikipedia article:

> Imagery, in a literary text, is an author's use of vivid and descriptive language to add depth to their work. It appeals to human senses to deepen the reader's understanding of the work. Powerful forms of imagery engage all of the senses.

Voices, being sound, can't *glimmer* in a visual sense, but the writer is using this type of language to communicate a like sense of beauty, in essence asking you to temporarily pretend/imagine a voice is something that you can look at.  Since this is a literary tactic you can assume the speaker or writer is trying to make someone feel important or special by saying this.

I wouldn't say this is necessarily high-quality imagery, because flowers don't really shine (unless they're glow-in-the-dark or sparkling in the sun because they're wet), but that's the intent of the speaker/writer in any case.

Comment: Let me just echo the note about the quality of this imagery. Even if flowers glimmered, and if the breeze had anything to do with it, it's not clear what dimension of a voice would glimmer. Perhaps the author had in mind "shimmer" and the association with wavering, trembling.